# Is my avacado plant dead or just frozen?

Tags: avocado, cold-weather, browning

My plant started to look like this after I left it outside all night because I forgot to bring it in. It's been About 2 or 3 weeks since this happend, I'm wondering if my plant is dead or if I can still bring it back to life. I cant add a picture so ill try my best to describe it. It's a dark green color, the leaves food towards the inside, the spined of the leaves are brown colored, and the stem of the plant is a dark green and brown color. The leaves are also crunchy but still dont fall down. I really need some advice, if any of yall have any please let me know, thank you.

Comment: Please post some photos of it

Comment: Its really not possible to advise without seeing a picture.   It does sound like the plant may be able to recover based on your description of the stem (depending on how dead it is it could take months - time will tell).  What type of avocado and how much cold was it exposed to?

Comment: It's a type A. It was exposed to about 30F one night. It and thank you for your response, I really appreciate you trying to help even with no picture.

Comment: 30F is marginal for most avocado - some species will tolerate it, some won't - but size of plant also plays a big part.    Hass is Marginal, Reed should be OK.  (I have had small Hass plants die on me - I purchased one which was 5 years old and it comfortably handles the half-a-dozen days a year we have frost here) Type A/B tells us about flowering pattern but does not tell much about hardiness.   Generally Mexican avocados are more cold tolerant other varieties.   At 30c, I would expect that even if the avo does loose its leaves it will likely come back next year.

Comment: https://www.californiaavocadogrowers.com/cultural-management-library/effects-freezes-avocado-trees and the section "The Avocado tree and frost" at https://www.californiaavocadogrowers.com/cultural-management-library/effects-freezes-avocado-trees may be useful to you.

Comment: https://ceventura.ucanr.edu/Com_Ag/Subtropical/Avocado_Handbook/Frost_Control_Freeze_Damage_/Rehabilitation_of_Freeze-Damaged_Citrus_and_Avocado_Trees_/ would imply you should be OK, but you may also want to do some pruning to prevent wood decay and secondary pathogens.